# Does with-redefs requires multiple arities?

Tags: clojurescript

I executed the following code (extracted from a real use case), and expected to get "Fake 2 a b":

```
(defn real-func  
  ([a] (real-func a "S"))
  ([a b] (real-func a b "S")) 
  ([a b c] (println "Real " a b c)))

(defn fake-func 
  ([a b] (println "Fake 2" a b)))

(deftest blah-test
  (testing "blah blah"
    (with-redefs [real-func fake-func]  (real-func "a" "b"))))
```

But instead I get an error:
`#object[TypeError TypeError: videra_web.effects.graphql_test.real_func.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$2 is not a function]`

Oddly, if I add another arity (any arity) to `fake-func` it works: e.g.

```
(defn fake-func 
  ([a b] (println "Fake 2" a b))
  ([a b c d e] (println "Fake 5" a b c d e))
)
```

Does this seem like a bug, or is there a language feature I don't understand?

Comment: I tested this with both planck and in a CLJS Repl on Node and the above code worked. Do you have a full repro as a CLJS repro and compilation script/instructions? CLJS "vars" aren't real and compiled away outside the REPL, so this may be the issue here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be running the code compiled with `:static-fns true` which prevents such things from working.

This defaults to true in `shadow-cljs` so if you are using that set `:compiler-options {:static-fns false}` in your build config.